# How can i run different spiders at the same time that they have different Crawler Runner Settings

Tags: scrapy

Default usage is:

```
import scrapy
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


class MySpider1(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your first spider definition
    ...

class MySpider2(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your second spider definition
    ...

configure_logging()
settings = get_project_settings()
runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)
runner.crawl(MySpider1)
runner.crawl(MySpider2)
d = runner.join()
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
```

My codes:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from twisted.internet import reactor

runner1 = CrawlerRunner(settings = {
        "FEEDS": {
        r"file:///C:\\Users\Messi\\1.json": {"format": "json", "overwrite": True}
        },
        })

runner2 = CrawlerRunner(settings = {
        "FEEDS": {
        r"file:///C:\\Users\Messi\\2.json": {"format": "json", "overwrite": True}
        },
        })

runner3 = CrawlerRunner(settings = {
        "FEEDS": {
        r"file:///C:\\Users\Messi\\3.json": {"format": "json", "overwrite": True}
        },
        })

 h = runner1.crawl(Live1)
 h.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
 a = runner2.crawl(Live2)
 a.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
 t = runner3.crawl(Live3)
 t.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())

 reactor.run()
```

Above code does not work!
How can i run different spiders at the same time that they have different crawler runner settings?
Settings are different so i used different variables for them runner1,runner2, runner3...
What should be the right usage? Could you please help me about this topic.
Thanks very much.

Comment: You can create [custom_settings](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?#scrapy.Spider.custom_settings) in each spider class and then you don't have to worry about it in the main script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in the comment, I think that using [custom_settings](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?#scrapy.Spider.custom_settings) is better.

Anyway, this what worked for me:

```py
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from tempbuffer.spiders.spider1 import ExampleSpider1
from tempbuffer.spiders.spider import ExampleSpider2


configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})

runner = CrawlerRunner(settings={
    "FEEDS": {
        r"1.json": {"format": "json", "overwrite": True}
    }})
runner.crawl(ExampleSpider1)

runner = CrawlerRunner(settings={
    "FEEDS": {
        r"2.json": {"format": "json", "overwrite": True}
    }})
runner.crawl(ExampleSpider2)

d = runner.join()
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())

reactor.run()
```

**Another way:**

```py
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from tempbuffer.spiders.spider1 import ExampleSpider1
from tempbuffer.spiders.spider import ExampleSpider2


configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
runner1 = CrawlerRunner(settings={
    "FEEDS": {
        r"1.json": {"format": "json", "overwrite": True}
    }})
runner2 = CrawlerRunner(settings={
    "FEEDS": {
        r"2.json": {"format": "json", "overwrite": True}
    }})

d = runner1.crawl(ExampleSpider2)
runner2.crawl(ExampleSpider1)
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())

reactor.run()
```

**1.json:**

```json
[
{"title": "Short Dress", "price": "$24.99"},
{"title": "Patterned Slacks", "price": "$29.99"},
{"title": "Short Chiffon Dress", "price": "$49.99"},
{"title": "Off-the-shoulder Dress", "price": "$59.99"},
{"title": "V-neck Top", "price": "$24.99"},
{"title": "Short Chiffon Dress", "price": "$49.99"},
{"title": "V-neck Top", "price": "$24.99"},
{"title": "V-neck Top", "price": "$24.99"},
{"title": "Short Lace Dress", "price": "$59.99"}
]
```

**2.json:**

```json
[
{"title": "Long-sleeved Jersey Top", "price": "$12.99"}
]
```

I kind of guessed the answer, I'm not sure which of this is better. If someone wants to correct/explain/clarify in the comments I'll be glad.

Comment: Thanks very much. With this this structure it worked. 1 space between runners that worked. d = runnerHome.crawl(Home){1space}runnerAway.crawl(Away){1space}runnerToday.crawl(Today)
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()